# How often should I do Calisthenic workouts?

Tags: exercise, bodyweight, calisthenics

I'm doing calisthenic workout for a year. So I'm not beginner. But I'm confused about the frequency of the routines. My workout program is like this:

```
Monday:   Lower Body
Tuesday:  Upper Body
Wednesday:Abs/Core
Thursday: Lower Body
Friday:   Upper Body
Saturday: Abs/Core
Sunday:   Rest
```

Every workout is about 30 mins, and my muscles are hurting for 2 days. (Abs/Core training is 15mins, but I'm going to change it) Is it a good split program? Or shall I do everything in one day and rest other day?

(Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: I think we might need more information about the specifics of the exercises. If you've been doing this for a year, your muscles shouldn't be hurting for 2 days. Your muscles should have gained endurance by now.

Comment: Yeah but I often change routines, and they are very difficult to do. One year ago I could do only 10 pull-ups max. But now I can do muscle ups etc. I'm just not sure about the frequency of this split program. Some professional calisthenics performers are doing their routines more often.

Comment: Actually, there's nothing stopping you *(depending on preferences and time)* from performing calisthenics daily. Your body builds tolerance against the exercises the more you perform them......and you get stronger as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try to work more often :)

Comment: Calisthenics are mainly conditioning and cardio exercises. You get better with the number of sets and reps performed. Equally awesome is the fact that you can perform many of them without any equipment, large space, or large quantities of time :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short Answer: *As often as you desire*

Calisthenics exercises are more similar to cardio exercises than weightlifting. They increase your flexibility and endurance, conditioning your body to perform better in relating exercises. Agility, better cardiovascular activities are also some of the benefits.

Calisthenics exercises' best features are in the number of repetitions and sets within a specified duration. The more repetitions that can be performed in the shortest time, the more endurance your body will build towards similar activities.

Because they're cardio-based, ***they can be performed as often as possible.*** There are many people that perform ***pull ups, push ups, and dips daily. Frankly, if you perform those 3 exercises more often, you'll develop a strong upper body and core.***

Calisthenics won't bulk you up; however, [they'll make your body more defined and well-toned](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhfLNN4BloY) [*(many bodybuilders actually incorporate calisthenics into their trainings)*](http://www.simplyshredded.com/).

So.....go nuts :)